# Delete Contents of a Column Based on Prefix

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a macro that currently deletes blank rows in column A and then a few unnecessary columns E and G. The report has changed on me and now in column E I must delete all the locations that begin with "MX " and there is just too many to be selecting one by one. Is there anything I can add to this current macro to delete all Locations that begin with "MX "? there are many other prefixes such as "US" "CA" but the one I need to delete are "MX"

Here is the current code:

```
Sub Delete()

    Dim cRow As Long
        cRow = 3
    Do While (IsEmpty(Cells(cRow, 1)))
      cRow = cRow + 1
    Loop
    cRow = cRow - 1

    'Rows("3:" & cRow).Select
    Rows("3:" & cRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Comment: In column E, what do you want to do if you find an entry with "MX"? Clear the contents or delete the cell and shift up?
Also, you're deleting the rows that have blank entries in column A; could any of these have wanted values in column E?

Comment: The blank in column A are not needed at all as they don't contain any relevant information for my report, and in column E cells containing "MX" the whole row should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
Sub Delete()

    Dim cRow As Long
        cRow = 3
    Do While (IsEmpty(Cells(cRow, 1)))
      cRow = cRow + 1
    Loop
    cRow = cRow - 1
    if range("E" & cRow).value like "MX*" then 'OR left(range("E" & cRow).value, 2) = "MX"
       Rows("3:" & cRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
       Columns("E:E").Select
       Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    end if 

    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Not sure if you'd still need G though.

Comment: For some reason it is not deleting the blanks in column A, it only deletes the E and G columns...